# Транзакции jdbc postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка. Как можно ее исправить? Программа не работает.

```
package pos;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Transaction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /**
         * Topping t = new Topping(); t.createTable(); t.insertData();
         */

        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;

        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/stock";
        String user = "capfer";
        String password = "123456";

        try {

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            st = con.createStatement();
            con.setAutoCommit(false);

            st.executeUpdate("UPDATE toppings SET topping_name = 'sausage' " + "WHERE id = 1");
            st.execute("INSERT INTO toppings (topping_name,topping_size, topping_qty) "
                    + "VALUES ('tomato', 'medium', '5')  ");

            st.executeUpdate("UPDATE toppings SET topping_name = 'pepper' " + "WHERE id = 2");
            st.execute("INSERT INTO toppings (topping_name,topping_size, topping_qty) "
                    + "VALUES ('mushrooms', 'xLarge', '7')  ");

            st.executeUpdate("UPDATE toppings SET topping_name = 'cheese' " + "WHERE id = 3");
            st.execute("INSERT INTO toppings (topping_name,topping_size, topping_qty) "
                    + "VALUES ('cabbage', 'small', '5')  ");

            con.commit();

        } catch (SQLException ex1) {
            // System.out.println("Fail committing data");
            if (con != null) {

                try {
                    con.rollback();
                } catch (SQLException ex2) {
                    Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Transaction.class.getName());
                    lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex1.getMessage(), ex1);
                    // System.out.println("Error rollingback the data");
                }
            }

            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Transaction.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex1.getMessage(), ex1);

        } finally {

            try {

                if (st != null) {

                    st.close();
                }

                if (con != null) {

                    con.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex1) {
                Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Transaction.class.getName());
                lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex1.getMessage(), ex1);
                // System.out.println("Error closing the files");
            }

            // System.out.println("Table toppings
            // successfullychanged!!!");

        }
    }

}
```

> мар 31, 2016 2:15:29 AM pos.Transaction main SEVERE: ОШИБКА: нулевое
>   значение в столбце "id" нарушает ограничение NOT NULL   Подробности:
>   Ошибочная строка содержит (null, tomato, medium, 5).
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: нулевое значение в столбце
>   "id" нарушает ограничение NOT NULL   Подробности: Ошибочная строка
>   содержит (null, tomato, medium, 5).   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:570)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:406)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:398)
>     at pos.Transaction.main(Transaction.java:32)

Answer (score 3):

> нулевое значение в столбце "id" нарушает ограничение NOT NULL

вам следует либо явно передавать значение для столбца *id* при выполнении оператора `insert into ...`, либо изменить описание этого столбца, присвоив ему, например, тип [serial](http://postgresql.ru.net/manual/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL).